# Android: Implementing SlidingMenu and ABS

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am trying to implement the SlidingMenu from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu together with http://actionbarsherlock.com/ and I came across a problem that I could not fix myself that's why I turned to the issues page on SlidingMenu's GitHub. But 2 days and I got no reply so I am gonna ask it here.

Basically on the example project provided by jfeinstein10, I copied the `SampleListFragment.java` file and I've named it `MenuListFragment.java` on my project. I've made a couple of changes but those should not be an issue.

I also copied the `menu.xml` from the layout directory but changed its name attribute to the previous file including the package.

Project builds properly and no errors are encountered. Time to run the project.

Now on my project's main activity, when I call the `setMenu(R.layout.menu);` statement during runtime, it gives me an error which tells me something about `ClassCastException` (cannot cast **com.dokgu.dota2stats.MenuListFragment** to **android.app.Fragment**).

I've tried a couple of things like change the MenuListFragment.java to extend the android.app.Fragment instead of ListFragment but it didn't solve the problem and more issues came up because of that.

So please, can anyone help me with this please? I really want to make this work.

You can find the issue here as well: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/546

Comment: Show us your code for the activity.

Comment: @Pork'n'Bunny - https://github.com/dokgu/Dota-2-Stats/blob/master/src/com/dokgu/dota2stats/MainActivity.java

Comment: @dokgu the response is in the same issue link:
cited: **I guess the problem is that you extend the class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment which itself extends the class android.support.v4.app.Fragment and this class is not android.app.Fragment. I'm not sure if this helps you but this is the reason for the ClassCastException.**

Answer (score 0):

Actionbarsherlork  supports the lower lever version since android 2.x while the slidingmenu needs android 3.0+.Maybe you can add the android-support-v4.jar ,with some fragment and activity in slidingmenu project extending to.

Comment: thats not true, i am using the sliding menu for versions 2.3 onwards. It is not completely true in saying that the sliding menu needs 3.0+

Comment: infact the sliding menu lib has this in its manifest: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />